# Remove unknown user for time machine

Tags: time-machine, catalina

I use time machine for backups.  I just updated to Catalina 10.15.4 from Catalina 10.15.3 and don't have permission for backups, unknown user is the only user that has read/write permissions.  How do I correct this problem ?  I've searched and tried a few answers but nothing seems to work. I use the terminal to check permissions of the directories/files and it shows that my user is the owner.

[image: Terminal showing my userid as owner of dir/files on time machine drive and Get Info from Finder]

[image]

Comment: Does TM work? Are you able to restore files from the TM application?

Comment: What file/folder is the "Sharing & Permissions" screenshot showing? I don't see anything like that in the terminal listing. BTW, the "(unknown)" in S&P doesn't necessarily have anything to do with the "_unknown" pseudo-user-account.

Comment: TM did work until I updated to 10.15.4.  I removed the TM drive in the process of fixing the error, now the TM application doesn't see the drive.  The "Sharing & Permissions" picture is the finder view of my sparse bundle folder on TM.  I'm baffled because finder shows permissions one way and terminal shows another.